# how to read a string using haskell

Tags: haskell

I don't get it how I can make it work, I tried many methods, but by all this is the only one who worked just a little! Can someone give me an idea ?

```
lcms :: (Integral a) => [a] -> a

parseIntList :: String -> [Int]
parseIntList s = [read x :: Int | x <- words s]

main = do
        a <- getLine --1,2,3
        let x = parseIntList a 
        print x -- [1,2,3]
        lcms  x --?
```

Answer (score 0):

`lcms x` is just a numerical value. Binding it directly in the `do` block of an `IO` action like `main` is like asking somebody “fetch the mail please, then buy some milk, then launch the missiles, then 36”. Well, that would surely prompt the reply *36 – what?*

If you want to *print* the result of `lcms x`, then say so.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    a <- getLine
    let x = parseIntList a 
    print x
    print $ lcms x
```

Comment: ok, I get it! Thank you very much! I see that I have a lot to learn ...